# Save Drop Down or Text Input Value in Same Column(Using Laravel 5.5)

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, forms, laravel

Scenerio:
If user select "other" option from the states Drop Down,text input will appear then user will enter the state manually....

My Issue is if user write state name in the text input,the value must go into the same column where the value of Drop Down going.In short,I have one column of state in my database and i want to save the state name given by user whether its coming from drop down or text input....

**State Input and Drop Down.....**

```
<select class="states" name="state" size="1" required>
       @include('auth.partials._states')
</select>

 <tr class="hidden state-input">
    <td align="right">&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>
    <td><input type="text" name="state" size="30" maxlength="100" value=""></td>
 </tr>
```

**Here is my JQuery for hiding and showing the text input**

```
$('.states').change(function(){
            var selected_option = $('.states').val();
            if (selected_option === 'other') {
                $('.state-input').removeClass('hidden');
            }
            else
            {
                $('.state-input').addClass('hidden');
            }
        });
```

**Here is my create new user function where state is going with other fields**

```
protected function create(array $data)
    {
        if(Input::hasFile('image'))
        {
            $email = Input::get('email');
            $image = Input::file('image');
            $image_extension = $image->guessClientExtension();
            $image_path = $image->storePubliclyAs('public/uploads/profile_images/images', $email . ".{$image_extension}");
        }


        $user = new User([
            'firstname' => $data['firstname'],
            'lastname' => $data['lastname'],
            'company' => $data['company'],
            'classification' => $data['classification'],
            'email' => $data['email'],
            'password' => bcrypt($data['password']),
            'image_url' => $image_path,
            'skills' => $data['skills'],
            'interests' => $data['interests'],
            'about' => $data['about'],
            'website' => $data['website'],
            'address' => $data['address'],
            'phone' => $data['phone'],
            'country' => $data['country'],
            'zipcode' => $data['zipcode'],
            'city' => $data['city'],
            'state' => $data['state'],
        ]);

        $user->save();
return $user;
}
```

Comment: On submit event you can assign the new state value to the `states` input.

Comment: How ?? Explain Please

Comment: See the answe I have posted

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$('#submit_button').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var newValue = $('custom_state_text_box_selector').val(); // Modify me
    $('.states').val(newValue);
    $('your_form_selector').submit();
});
```

And also there is no need to set the `name` of the text field for enter the custom state. And also you give the same `name` as of the `select` dropdown. Remove it.
Or 
You can also do it on the server side. Give your text box name "custom_state" and then

```
'state' => $data['state'] == "other" ? $data['custom_state'] : $data['state']
```

Comment: Type error: Argument 1 passed to Illuminate\Auth\SessionGuard::login() must be an instance of Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Authenticatable, array given, called in C:\Ampps\www\gcf\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\RegistersUsers.php on line 35

Comment: Are you sure, the error you got is because of this `'state' => $data['state'] == "other" ? $data['custom_state'] : $data['state']` ?

Comment: Also I have a multi value selected drop down...i want to set a limit of 5 value....user can maximum select 5 value....do you know how can i set this limit??

Comment: Are you using any select plugin for multi selection or just use the simple select box because plugin provides the options for setting the limit of selection if you use and look at the documentation